# Allow HTTP POST request to .NET API from an Arduino

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, esp8266

I have an application up and running on Azure and I'm trying to post data from an ESP8266 to `https://myApplication.azurewebservices.net/api/call`. But I'm not getting anywhere. The ESP8266 seems to have trouble handling HTTPS and so I thought I would try to enable HTTP POST requests.

My startup class looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

I thought that by allowing anyheaders, anyorigin, and anymethod would allow me to post HTTP requests.

But trying it in Postman still returns a 404 not found if I do `http://myApplication.azurewebservices.net/api/call`, but it does work if I use `https://`.

How can I make my application accept the exact same request but with HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically enable HTTP requests for your App Service in the Azure Portal.

```
Dashboard > App Service > Custom Domains > disable "HTTPS only"
```